# even the snapshhot has data still it shows elses condition for 1 second and then again goes to if and execute

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

this is the condition. I am checking for a user to keep logged in using firebase auth data. it is performing the if and else statement executing at the same time  so what check should I  perform to solve this please help

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
   return screenToBeReturn(snapshot);
  }
);

if(snapshot.hasData &&(Utility.userId != null && Utility.userId != 0)) {
        print("user id there ${Utility.userId}");
        print("auth gate");
        if (Utility.statusCode == "200") {
          print("there");
          return const Dashboard();
        }
        else if (Utility.statusCode == "300") {
          return const WaitingPage();
        }
      }
      /*else if( !snapshot.hasData || ( Utility.userId ==0)) {
        print("am here");
        return IntroView();
      }*/
      else{
        return IntroView();
      }
```

```
if(snapshot.hasData &&(Utility.userId != null && Utility.userId != 0)) {
        print("user id there ${Utility.userId}");
        print("auth gate");
        if (Utility.statusCode == "200") {
          print("there");
          return const Dashboard();
        }
        else if (Utility.statusCode == "300") {
          return const WaitingPage();
        }
      }
      /*else if( !snapshot.hasData || ( Utility.userId ==0)) {
        print("am here");
        return IntroView();
      }*/
      else{
        return IntroView();
      }
```

Comment: try printing/debugging the snapshot, issue can be `Utility.userId != 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gaurav Patil as firebase auth data is awaited ....for first time execution snapshot data will be null so it will visit else part and after listening callback snapshot will have some data....hence if executed